# ibatis insert into a DB2 table results in a lock that prevents a trigger working

Tags: sql, db2, ibatis, triggers

I am writing an INSERT into a DB2 table that uses my inserted record as a trigger and have been accused of being the culprit for locking the file and preventing the trigger from working.

Currently I can write the record but it hangs my application and I get no response back from the DB2 database. (although it does write !).

I have been told I might be writing using "UPDATE mode" but I have done nothing specific other than not actually setting any mode:

```
  <resultMap id = "insertEntry" class = "customer">
        <result property = "supplierNumber"     column = "SUPN"/>
        <result property = "status"          column = "STAT"/>
        <result property = "timeAccepted"   column = "TIMEACC"/>
        <result property = "dateAccepted"   column = "DATEACC"/>
        <result property = "dateCompleted"   column = "DATECOMP"/>
    </resultMap>


<insert id = "insertCUSTRecord" parameterClass="insertEntry">
INSERT INTO ##AKQQ3
(SUPN, STAT, TIMEACC, DATEACC, DATECOMP)
VALUES (#supplierNumber#, #status#, #timeAccepted#, #dateAccepted#, #dateCompleted#)
</insert>
```

I can only guess at the cause of my application hanging and one guess is that is a result of not having set the relevant mode on an an INSERT statement but I have no idea as to which is relevant from a choice of ibatis' IN, OUT and INOUT parameters.

The RPG team have told me to attempt to somehow try and read the record I have just inserted to release this lock and was wondering if any of these ibatis modes provides that functionality.

The docs state "If a parameter is OUT or INOUT, the actual value of the parameter object property will be changed" but I'm somewhat confused as to what object this refers to. Could setting all my insert values to IN be what I'm looking for ?

I should mention that I have used the Squirrel SQL client to attempt the same insert (using the jt400 JDBC driver) and it hangs and get no confirmation back from the database despite having written the record.

In my application I have resorted to a "fire and forget" approach of dealing with not having a response back from the DB2 database via an ExecutorService that I kill after 3 seconds although I know this is not an ideal solution.

My program integrates struts with spring and ibatis, the code that calls the insert is as follows:

```
public void insertIntoAKQA(CustomerTriggerDetailsBean customerTriggerDetails) {
    SqlMapClientTemplate template = getSqlMapClientTemplate();
    template.insert("insertCUSTRecord", customerTriggerDetails);
}
```

Comment: You may not actually be writing the record, not permanently.  When you write a record, it will put a temporary lock on it until the record is committed - if you don't commit it (or operate under a no-commit strategy), killing the process will actually cause the record to be removed!  `IN`/`OUT` parameters are unimportant here, this is entirely on other things your program is doing (or not).  Triggers should still run if you're in a transaction, in most cases.  We need to see your program, and maybe the trigger as well.

Comment: I have edited my original question to include the code that calls the SQL statement. The trigger is most likely in RPG and I will see what code / facts I can obtain. Perhaps there a chance I am not responsible for the locking ?

Comment: ... that doesn't help much, we need to see the implementation of `SqlMapClientTemplate` you're using.  Your Spring config files could also be part of the problem (ie, if they're using expecting you to manually commit, but you never do).  You appear to be throwing away the primary key that the statement should return.  I'm also a bit worried about the fact that you pass something labelled `'Trigger'` as the parameter object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be an RPG trigger which was badly written. Until they resolved it I did however manage a workaround with the Java ServiceExecutor which gave me back control of my application after an assigned time.